# str_replace - Hide Phone Number Formats

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to hide dif formats of telephone numbers in a string PHP.
Getting so confused with all the help out there....

What function can I use to hide any of the following phone formats in a string that can contain Text, symbols and numbers?

(xxx) xxx-xxxx
xxx xxx xxxx

xxxxxxxxxx

+xx xx xxx xxxx

xxx - xxx xxxx

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
echo preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', '(+31) 111-2222 333 444 '); // 311112222333444
```